# Outer join operator not allowed with OR in my WHERE clause - Error: ORA-01719

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I need to check for the conditions at the bottom, but I cannot change use OR because of the (+) that are involved. I did not set that part up, so I am not sure how to rearrange it. Can someone tell me what I could do to get those conditions to go through?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t.tkt_sid,
  ts.tkt_sts_dsc,
  tp.prty_dsc,
  a.agt_cont_nbr,
  au_a.user_nm assigned_to,
  t.rcd_lst_user_ts 
FROM
  afp_asd.tkt t,
  afp_asd.tkt_prty tp,
  afp_asd.tkt_sts ts,
  afp_asd.tkt_type tt,
  afp_asd.tkt_log tl,
  afp_asd.agt a,
  afp_asd.asd_user au_a,
  afp_asd.asd_user au_c,
  afp_asd.asd_user au_l,
  afp_asd.asd_user au_log,
  afp_asd.prb_area pa1,
  afp_asd.prb_area pa2,
  afp_asd.prb_area pa3,
  afp_asd.mktg_org mo,
  afp_asd.src_sys ss,
  afp_asd.agt ofc,
  afp_asd.co c,
  afp_asd.agt_sts ast 
WHERE (
    t.prty_cd = tp.prty_cd 
    AND t.tkt_sts_cd = ts.tkt_sts_cd 
    AND t.tkt_type_cd = tt.tkt_type_cd 
    AND t.agt_sid = a.agt_sid 
    AND t.assigned_id = au_a.asd_user_id 
    AND t.rcd_crt_user_id = au_c.asd_user_id (+) 
    AND t.lst_updater_id = au_l.asd_user_id 
    AND t.tkt_sid = tl.tkt_sid 
    AND t.prb_area_sid = pa3.prb_area_sid 
    AND tl.rcd_crt_user_id = au_log.asd_user_id 
    AND pa3.prb_hier_sid = pa2.prb_area_sid (+) 
    AND pa2.prb_hier_sid = pa1.prb_area_sid (+) 
    AND a.mktg_org_cd = mo.mktg_org_cd 
    AND a.src_sys_cd = mo.src_sys_cd 
    AND a.src_sys_cd = ss.src_sys_cd 
    AND a.ofc_id = ofc.agt_cont_nbr (+) 
    AND a.src_sys_cd = ofc.src_sys_cd (+) 
    AND a.co_sid = c.co_sid (+) 
    AND a.agt_sts_cd = ast.agt_sts_cd 
    AND tl.rcd_lst_user_ts >= :b_start_date 
    AND t.user_grp_sid = :b_group_id
  ) 
  AND (
    (TKT_STS_DSC NOT LIKE 'Completed') 
    OR (
      tp.prty_dsc = 'High' 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'Pending' 
      AND t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 2
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 3 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'In Progress' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'High'
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 15 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'In Progress' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'Medium'
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 28 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'In Progress' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'Low'
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 7 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'Pending' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'High'
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 21 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'Pending' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'Medium'
    ) 
    OR (
      t.rcd_lst_user_ts < SYSDATE- 43 
      AND ts.tkt_sts_dsc = 'Pending' 
      AND tp.prty_dsc = 'Low'
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY ASSIGNED_TO,
  PRTY_DSC
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the old `FROM TableA,TableB WHERE ...` join syntax. Just don't.

Instead, write out your joins individually:

```
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON ...
LEFT JOIN TableC ON ...
```

This isn't just a general rant against the old syntax: using the new (I say "new", but it's more than 20 years old now), *standard* syntax **will** fix your problem in this case.

Comment: Okay, I get that. I don't really understand how to convert those outer joins in this specifically.

Comment: @user3389817 That's the whole problem: neither do we (or the Oracle DB). When you mix "OR" conditions in with outer join conditions, there is more than one possible meaning for that query, and so we can't tell you which one is right. The newer syntax is more verbose, but when used there will be exactly one meaning for the query, guaranteed.

Comment: I understand that part, but I'm saying I do not know which ones to connect in the WHERE and FROM. Is there any way you could change your example with code from my syntax?

Comment: @user3389817 the point of my comment is that we don't know either: there is more than possible interpretation of your current code. That's why Oracle is complaining at you.

Comment: I'm not following. If I take out the OR stuff, it works perfectly. I just need to get the OR to work, and I don't know how to change the Joins because I don't know which table is 'TableA/B/C'

Comment: Tables A, B, C, etc, are the just the first, second, and third etc tables used in your query, in the order listed. The INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN are just examples to show both types of join.